# Fragment, button under ScrollView pulled out of screen under navigation menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I hope you can help me, I'm making a fragment layout with a button fixed at the bottom of the screen, but when the fragment is displayed, the button hides under the android navigation bar(the black one with home, back and menu button). This is the code of the fragment layout to be inflated:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/questionFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ottegui.ottegui_android.Fragments.QuestionFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_q_title"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Next Question"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The RadioGroup in there is filled dynamically on Fragment class.
TextView is also set from Fragment class.

This is an image of the button under the navigation, you can see only a purple border, I want it to be at the bottom of the fragment. I think that maybe the ConstraitLayout was a bad choice because on some tutorial I saw always use FrameLayout(I started to build on my own, that's why I user ConstraitLayout)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` is not "icky", anymore than other kinds of layout. For your purpose, you have to do two things:

1. Make a full edge-to-edge two-directional chain using the immediate children of the `ConstraintLayout`.
2. Declare the height attribute of those children according to your needs.

You have two children of `ConstraintLayout` in your xml, the `ScrollView` called `content` and the `LinearLayout` called `linearLayoutQuestionButton`. Each of those layout are connected to `parent` on the left and right sides, while the former is connected to `parent` at the top and the latter is connected to `parent` at the bottom. However, they are **not connected to each other**! Change this, by adding

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayoutQuestionButton"
```

to `content` and

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content"
```

to `linearLayoutQuestionButton`.

Then you want the first child (`content`) to fill all of the available height except for the height of the second child (`linearLayoutQuestionButton`). The correct value for doing this is neither `match_parent` nor `wrap_content`, but somewhat counterintuitively

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Your full layout will then look like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/questionFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ottegui.ottegui_android.Fragments.QuestionFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayoutQuestionButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_q_title"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Next Question"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Well explained with all the necessary information to understand why and the stuff necessary to make it work. Answer accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing by the layout, you are coming from iOS development? I would recommend getting rid of the icky constraint layout and going with relative.
Align the scroll view to the top, the button layout below the scroll view and aligned to the bottom.